# Mysql on select update records selected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have mysql table posts

```
Posts
  PostId (int)
  PostTitle (varchar)
  PostContent (text)
  PostHits (int)
  PostStatus (varchar)
```

and I read these records on select query like

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE PostStatus LIKE 'ALIVE';
```

is it possible that all records increment their value of `PostHits` on each select if they qualify where clause? if yes what is the best possible way, currently I am doing it using two queries select and then update based on `where id in(all selected posts ids)`. I am looking for single query solution.

Comment: Increment by how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
UPDATE posts
SET PostHits = PostHits + 1
WHERE PostStatus LIKE 'ALIVE'
```

Using `SELECT` only

```
SELECT
    PostId,
    PostTitle,
    PostContent,
    PostHits + 1 AS PostHits,
    PostStatus
FROM posts
WHERE PostStatus LIKE 'ALIVE'
```

Comment: this is a separate query, I want to make this update inside select query

Comment: quite similar to your second query but your second query doesn't update table records it just show incremented values on select.

Comment: how? these are two separate queries i want single query solution, assume that my query select 20 records, should i really execute 20 extra queries to update each record's hits?

Comment: No! All you have to do is execute the `UPDATE`. It will update all rows with `PostStatus = 'ALIVE'`.